# Equivalent resistance between points K and M

Tags: physics

[image]

The equivalent resistance between K and L is given $3\Omega$. How do I evaluate  the equivalent resistance between K and M?

I couldn't think of anything so far. Could I get your dear assistance?

Regards

Comment: I suggest you ask your question [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Call the resistance of one quarter of the ring R

Then between $K$ and $L$ you have a resistance of $1R$ (the short way, counter clockwise ) in parallel with another resistance of $3R$ (the long way, clockwise) resulting in total of $3\text{ }\Omega$.   So you can find $R$, right?

Then between $K$ and $M$ you have a resistance of $2R$ (counter clockwise ) in parallel with another resistance of $2R$ (clockwise).

Since you just found the value of $R$, you can find this resistance...

Comment: Can you show it by drawing a diagram if necessary?